# Replace SpringFox @Api tag with SpringDoc tag

Tags: spring-boot, springfox, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have this SpringFox @Api tag:

```
@Api(hidden = true)
```

I tried to replace it with:

```
@Tag(hidden = true)
```

But where is not option `hidded=true`

What is the proper way to replace this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a `hidden` attribute on the `@Tag` annotation because it doesn't make a lot of sense to have an API in a public facing class but then not include it in the documentation.

The suggested approach is to move all such methods into a separate class of their own and not tag that class with the `@Tag` annotation. Then you can set the property `springdoc.auto-tag-classes` to `false` so that Springdoc doesn't pick it up in the `default` tag.

If at all you need to have APIs in a class that's tagged with `@Tag` you should annotate the method with `@Operation(hidden = true)` and that should hide the method from tag.